# Can we use Flash content in an Android application?

Tags: android, flash, android-4.2-jelly-bean

Will Flash content work in applications on Android Jelly Bean, as it's not supporting Flash... Share your knowledge about this..

Comment: Please be aware that tags are not keywords.  That is, tagging your question with `jelly` and `bean` does not mean you are talking about the Android version code-named Jelly Bean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether mobile devices support Flash / AIR player runtime plugins or not, apps may always be packaged with Captive Runtime.

A captive runtime bundle is a package that includes your application code along with a dedicated version of the runtime. An application packaged in this manner uses the bundled runtime instead of the shared runtime installed elsewhere.

Users can then run the application even on a device that does not already have AIR installed on it. Depending on the platform to which you are exporting the package, you can use a captive runtime or a shared runtime.

Captive runtime is mandatory for iOS devices.

Flash apps packaged with captive runtime may be deployed regardless of mobile browser Flash integration.

Comment: thanks for your help...couldnt vote up due to a newbie here :)